# Marketing Cloud ID override

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I'm using the Adobe Marketing Cloud ID Service (MCID) on an Adobe Analytics deployment.

Now I need to overwrite the native ID with a custom one and I'm thinking to exploit the s.visitorID variable.

As stated here: [Visitors identification hierarchy](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visid_overview.html) , s.visitorID would be considered primarily to the default MID identification, but my question is:

Would the s.visitorID value used exactly like the default MID within the Marketing Cloud Suite (spread across solutions)?

Comment: No. It will only override for AA visitor identification.  MCID Service does not currently have ability to override mid= itself to be used across all tools

Comment: Thx @CrayonViolent; to be more clear: my mobile app (with MCID installed) is generating a mid that is passed to webviews where I was supposing to store its value into the s.visitorID to keep visitor&session. I don't need to override the mid at the start, but to keep its value.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you are trying to accomplish.  If you have MCID installed in your app, and then have the js version installed on a web page, it will automatically do its thing behind the scenes to use the same mid= value for both, no need to explicitly set `s.visitorID` or anything. Is this what you meant, or something else?

Comment: At the moment no MCID is deployed on the web page, because I was attempting to pass the app value and use s.visitorID to keep it. Even though my web page would use the MCID itself (via DTM, not js), I suppose the visitor would be identified as new when landing to it, because no tied to the app previous session. This is the reason why I'd leverage the s.visitorID. How could the web page MCID use the same mid behind the scenes?

Comment: So if you have DTM implemented, why not just implement the MCID service in DTM?

Comment: I might do it, but this is not the point. How could I keep the same visitor and visit from the app without an overriding way? I suppose the user would be identified with a new mid when landing on the webview...

Comment: Going straight to the point and making example: in the app my mid is "1234", than I run the first webview, where the MCID is now deployed via DTM, and my new mid would be "6789", not the same as I expected. We tried this morning to do that..thus I need to pass the original value from the app and overwrite it in the webview

Comment: Currently there is no way to explicitly set the mid value. Closest to what you want is to explicitly set `s.visitorID`. But you must set it everywhere with the same value, which overrides mid. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/xdevice_visid.html

Comment: Also you must continue to set it on every hit everywhere ever.

Comment: actually wait, this sound like the (SDK) [appendToURL](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/android/mc_methods.html) and (JS) [Append Visitor ID Function](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-appendvisitorid.html) may be what you are looking for

Comment: they are @CrayonViolent, and we're leveraging them to send the VisitorID (MCID) to the webview inside the useragent string. From there we are storing the value into s.visitorID. By this way we keep the visitor/visit but, probably, we lose the MCID service functionality as identification across the suite tools

Comment: okay so you don't want to set `s.visitorID` at all, unless you intend to set it everywhere every time. It overrides everything else and *does not fall back and associate with mid*. So if you set `s.visitorID` in only one place you are effectively breaking the visitor id chain all the same.

Comment: if you are using the mid url append methods then you *should* see mid pop with the same value carried over on the web view. If you are *not* seeing this then you either implemented it incorrectly, OR you may need to update to a more recent AA AppMeasurement lib version.

Comment: You've been so helpful @CrayonViolent, as usual, but I'm not loading all the webviews via GET requests; some are by POST calls and this way would not work. We are thinking about removing the MCID both from the app and from the webviews

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is currently an offical way to override the MID.

Something to try though -
If you are using a first-party data collection server (the s_vi cookie is on a domain you own and writable from the app) you could try putting the MID value from the app directly into the s_vi cookie before MC code on the page runs (potentially in webview cookie store?)
MCID Service would then use that cookie value as a 'migrated' visitor ID during an MCID migration period.

Comment: Thx @Nils but there's an official way as explaind here: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-overwrite-visitor-id.html. Unfortunately this way works only when passing mid via URL GET param [by the Visitor.appendVisitorIDsTo(url) method]. In my case we cannot always append a param because some webviews are loaded via POST requests

Comment: Yes, you're correct, that is a relatively new method, but may not work for your scenario. Have you tried the cookie method I described above? It is a bit of a hack but I'm pretty sure it will work.